# Adding retry to future sequence for running Databricks notebooks in parallel in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, future, databricks, azure-databricks

I use the below code from Databricks itself on how to run its notebook in parallel in Scala, https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html#run-multiple-notebooks-concurrently . I am trying to add retry feature where if one of the notebooks in the sequence failed, it will retry that notebook based on the retry value I passed to it.

Here is the parallel notebook code from Databricks:

```
//parallel notebook code

import scala.concurrent.{Future, Await}
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.util.control.NonFatal

case class NotebookData(path: String, timeout: Int, parameters: Map[String, String] = Map.empty[String, String])

def parallelNotebooks(notebooks: Seq[NotebookData]): Future[Seq[String]] = {
  import scala.concurrent.{Future, blocking, Await}
  import java.util.concurrent.Executors
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
  import com.databricks.WorkflowException

  val numNotebooksInParallel = 5
  // If you create too many notebooks in parallel the driver may crash when you submit all of the jobs at once. 
  // This code limits the number of parallel notebooks.
  implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numNotebooksInParallel))
  val ctx = dbutils.notebook.getContext()
  
  Future.sequence(
    notebooks.map { notebook => 
      Future {
        dbutils.notebook.setContext(ctx)
        if (notebook.parameters.nonEmpty)
          dbutils.notebook.run(notebook.path, notebook.timeout, notebook.parameters)
        else
          dbutils.notebook.run(notebook.path, notebook.timeout)
      }
      .recover {
        case NonFatal(e) => s"ERROR: ${e.getMessage}"
      }
    }
  )
}
```

This is an example of how I am calling the above code to run multiple examples notebooks:

```
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.language.postfixOps
val notebooks = Seq(
  NotebookData("Notebook1", 0, Map("client"->client)),
  NotebookData("Notebook2", 0, Map("client"->client))
)
val res = parallelNotebooks(notebooks)
Await.result(res, 3000000 seconds) // this is a blocking call.
res.value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this to work:

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

def tryNotebookRun (path: String, timeout: Int, parameters: Map[String, String] = Map.empty[String, String]): Try[Any] = {
  Try(
    if (parameters.nonEmpty){
      dbutils.notebook.run(path, timeout, parameters)
    }
    else{
      dbutils.notebook.run(path, timeout)
    }
  )
}

//parallel notebook code

import scala.concurrent.{Future, Await}
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.util.control.NonFatal


def runWithRetry(path: String, timeout: Int, parameters: Map[String, String] = Map.empty[String, String], maxRetries: Int = 2) = {
  var numRetries = 0
  while (numRetries < maxRetries){
    
    tryNotebookRun(path, timeout, parameters) match {
      case Success(_) => numRetries = maxRetries
      case Failure(_) => numRetries = numRetries + 1      
    }    
  }
}

case class NotebookData(path: String, timeout: Int, parameters: Map[String, String] = Map.empty[String, String])

def parallelNotebooks(notebooks: Seq[NotebookData]): Future[Seq[Any]] = {
  import scala.concurrent.{Future, blocking, Await}
  import java.util.concurrent.Executors
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
  import com.databricks.WorkflowException

  val numNotebooksInParallel = 5
  // If you create too many notebooks in parallel the driver may crash when you submit all of the jobs at once. 
  // This code limits the number of parallel notebooks.
  implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numNotebooksInParallel))
  val ctx = dbutils.notebook.getContext()
  
  Future.sequence(
    notebooks.map { notebook => 
      Future {
        dbutils.notebook.setContext(ctx)
        runWithRetry(notebook.path, notebook.timeout, notebook.parameters)
      }
      .recover {
        case NonFatal(e) => s"ERROR: ${e.getMessage}"
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Glad to know that your issue has resolved. You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one attempt. Since your code does not compile, I inserted a few dummy classes.

Also, you did not fully specify the desired behavior, so I made some assumptions. Only five retries will be made for each connection. If any of the Futures are still failing after five retries, then the entire Future is failed. Both of these behaviors can be changed, but since you did not specify, I am not sure what it is you want.

If you have questions or would like me to make an alteration to the program, let me know in the comments section.

```
object TestNotebookData extends App{
  //parallel notebook code

  import scala.concurrent.{Future, Await}
  import scala.concurrent.duration._
  import scala.util.control.NonFatal

  case class NotebookData(path: String, timeout: Int, parameters: Map[String, String] = Map.empty[String, String])

  case class Context()

  case class Notebook(){
    def getContext(): Context = Context()
    def setContext(ctx: Context): Unit = ()
    def run(path: String, timeout: Int, paramters: Map[String, String] = Map()): Seq[String] = Seq()
  }
  case class Dbutils(notebook: Notebook)

  val dbutils = Dbutils(Notebook())


  def parallelNotebooks(notebooks: Seq[NotebookData]): Future[Seq[Seq[String]]] = {
    import scala.concurrent.{Future, blocking, Await}
    import java.util.concurrent.Executors
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

    // This code limits the number of parallel notebooks.
    implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numNotebooksInParallel))
    val ctx = dbutils.notebook.getContext()

    val isRetryable = true
    val retries = 5

    def runNotebook(notebook: NotebookData): Future[Seq[String]] = {
      def retryWrapper(retry: Boolean, current: Int, max: Int): Future[Seq[String]] = {
        val fut = Future {runNotebookInner}
        if (retry && current < max) fut.recoverWith{ _ => retryWrapper(retry, current + 1, max)}
        else fut
      }

      def runNotebookInner() = {
        dbutils.notebook.setContext(ctx)
        if (notebook.parameters.nonEmpty)
          dbutils.notebook.run(notebook.path, notebook.timeout, notebook.parameters)
        else
          dbutils.notebook.run(notebook.path, notebook.timeout)
      }

      retryWrapper(isRetryable, 0, retries)
    }


    Future.sequence(
      notebooks.map { notebook =>
        runNotebook(notebook)
      }
    )
  }

  val notebooks = Seq(
    NotebookData("Notebook1", 0, Map("client"->"client")),
    NotebookData("Notebook2", 0, Map("client"->"client"))
  )
  val res = parallelNotebooks(notebooks)
  Await.result(res, 3000000 seconds) // this is a blocking call.
  res.value
}
```

Comment: thank you for the reply! I applied your code with one fix, 'val numNotebooksInParallel = ' was missing.

there was also this error inside databricks:

command-1656177338010954:38: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Throwable => scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[String]]
 required: PartialFunction[Throwable,scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[String]]]
        if (retry && current < max) fut.recoverWith{ _ => retryWrapper(retry, current + 1, max)}

Comment: Can someone help me please? In the above code snippet, how can I run this program? Trying to test. Thanks!